# React to property changes in JSON object using recursive components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to visualize a tree structure in Vue.js.

A small tree looks like the following:

```
{
"label": "outlook",
"edges": {
    "== sunny": {
        "label": "== sunny",
        "node": {
            "label": "humidity",
            "edges": {
                "<= 82": {
                    "label": "<= 82",
                    "node": {
                        "label": true
                    }
                },
                "> 82": {
                    "label": "> 82",
                    "node": {
                        "label": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This might not be the most intuitive data structure for a tree, but I ended up with this since I need to display the labels for both the nodes and the edges.

The JSON object is used as input for a `Tree` component with the following template:

```html
<template id="tree-template">
    <div class="tree clearfix">
        <node v-ref:node :node-data="treeData"></node>
    </div>
</template>
```

The `Node` component looks as follows:

```html
<template id="node-template">
    <div class="node">
        <div class="node__children" v-if="hasChildren">
            <div class="node__child" v-for="edge in nodeData.edges">
                <node :node-data="edge.node"></node>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The problem now is that the child `node` components do not reflect changes made to the `edges` property of the JSON object from above. For visualization purposes, the object gets constructed step-by-step using the generator pattern. I.e., I first start off with something like this:

```
{
"label": "outlook",
"edges": {
    "== sunny": {
        "label": "== sunny",
        "node": {}
    }
}
}
```

Where the `node` property of edge `== sunny` is an empty object. In the next step, that `node` gets created and is set in the tree data.

I know that changes to object properties are not watched by default, but should still trigger view updates when using Vue.js' `$set()` method:

`this.$set('treeData.edges["== sunny"].node', node);`

However, this change is only reflected at the top level (i.e. in the `tree` component), which I can see by outputting `{{ treeData | json }}`. Also, in the `node` component embedded in `tree`, `{ nodeData | json }}` reflects this change. (I also tried `this.$set('treeData', treeData)` after having manipulated `treeData`, but without success).

But if I output `{{ edge.node }}` in the `v-for` directive inside the `node` component, it remains the empty object set during the initialization (and therefore no subsequent nodes are rendered).

I also tried to define an own watcher for this both in the `tree` and `node` component, but to no avail:

```js
// ...
watch: {
  'nodeData': {
    handler: function(val, oldVal) {
        console.log('nodeData updated:');
        console.log(val);
    },
      deep: true
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can get the (recursive) `node` component to be aware of the changes to `treeData` / `nodeData`?

Comment: They should be, since all data is sync'd from parent to child by default.  This seems like another issue.  Maybe since the `edges` value is an object not an array, you need to use the `<div class="node__child" v-for="(key, edge) in nodeData.edges">` syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately no improvement using `v-for="(key, edge) in nodeData.edges"`. It seems that the data updates are at least partially working, since I see the changes when outputting `{{ nodeData | json }}`, it's just that the `node` property for an edge inside the `v-for` is not reflecting that change and remains empty.